# Upload file to SFTP server using VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, sftp

I need to upload a file to SFTP server. I am using VB.NET 2008.

How can I upload a simple `.csv` file from my local computer to SFTP server using port number, user name and password, etc? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A commonly used open source SFTP library for .NET is [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET).

With it, you can use a code like this:

```
Dim client As SftpClient = New SftpClient("example.com", "username", "password")
client.Connect()

Using stream As Stream = File.OpenRead("C:\local\path\some.csv")
    client.UploadFile(stream, "/remote/path/some.csv")
End Using
```

---

There are other libraries too. If you need more high-level functions, like uploading all files in a directory or even complete directory structures, you may find *my* [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) useful.

With WinSCP, you can use a code like this to upload all .csv files:

```
Dim sessionOptions As New SessionOptions
With sessionOptions
    .Protocol = Protocol.Sftp
    .HostName = "example.com"
    .UserName = "username"
    .UserName = "password"
    .SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 ..."
End With

Using session As New Session
    session.Open(sessionOptions)

    session.PutFiles("C:\local\path\*.csv", "/remote/path/*").Check()
End Using
```

[WinSCP GUI can generate an upload code template](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating), like the one above, for you.

*Though, WinSCP .NET assembly is not a native .NET library, it's just a .NET wrapper around a console application. So it has its own limitations.*

Comment: Thank you so much dear Mr. Martin Prikryl. Its working so smoothly and definately you have saved my lot of time. Thanks again and may ALLAH give the HIDAYAT and bless you all the time