# Using SSH Renci with VB.net how do I upload a file to a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: vb.net, ssh

I have been trying to workout how to upload a file from a Windows PC to a Raspberry pi using the Renci SSH with VB.net. There are plenty of C# demos and tutorials but nothing on file uploading with VB.net.

I have used the following code:

https://github.com/muxall/Automation/blob/master/CiscoSshClientTest/CiscoSshClientTest/Form1.vb

This code allows me to send commands

Comment: Do you have any relevant code at all? Please [edit] your question to include the code that you have, even if it doesn't work or isn't complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found this very simple answer online...

[Upload file to SFTP server using VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48556236/upload-file-to-sftp-server-using-vb-net)

```
` 

   SFTPHost = "192.168.1.xx"
        SFTPPort = "22"
        SFTPUsername = "pipi"
        SFTPPassword = "xxxxx"
        SFTPFolderSource = ""
        SFTPFolderDest = ""

    '   Dim sClient As New SftpClient(SFTPHost, SFTPPort, SFTPUsername, SFTPPassword)
    '   sClient.Connect()

    Dim client As SftpClient = New SftpClient(SFTPHost, SFTPPort, SFTPUsername, SFTPPassword)
    client.Connect()
    Try


        Using stream As Stream = File.OpenRead("C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\xxxxx.txt")
            client.UploadFile(stream, "xxxxx.txt")
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try`
```